# Trying to enable/disable a hyperlink using code given. For some reason it doesnt work as expected

Tags: sql, jsp, resultset

Following is my code snippet. Even when the rs.getString(10) is NULL in the table, I am getting the Download link enabled instead of it to display "Cannot Download".

```
<table border="1" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
   <tr>
      <th>FileName</th>
      <th>Ip</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Download</th>
   </tr>
   <%
         Connection con = DbConnector.getConnection();
         PreparedStatement pstm = null;
         //PreparedStatement pstm1 = null;
         String sql = "SELECT * FROM transaction t LEFT JOIN mykeys m ON t.FileID = m.FileID UNION ALL SELECT * FROM transaction t RIGHT JOIN mykeys m ON t.FileID = m.FileID WHERE t.FileID IS NULL and t.status='Success'";
         pstm = con.prepareStatement(sql);
         ResultSet rs = pstm.executeQuery();
         while (rs.next()) 
         {
           %>
              <tr>
                  <td><%=rs.getString(2)%></td>
                  <td><%=rs.getString(4)%></td>
                  <td><%=rs.getString(5)%></td>
         <%
               if(rs.getString(10) != null)
               {
                 %>
                 <td><a href="FileDownload?ip=<%=rs.getString(4)%>&filename=<%=rs.getString(2)%>">Download</a></td>
                 <%
               }
               else
               {
                %>
                <td>Cannot Download</td>
                <%
               }%>
               </tr>
         <%
         }
   %>
</table>
```

Comment: if the link is enabled, what is the hyperlink? is it '....&filename=NULL' ?

Comment: nopes it points to the actual files correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue. The if condition is making a reference to null which is different than making a reference to the string "NULL". My code is now working as expected.